# how to grant permission for device id through Pending intent in android

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I have two apps A & B. I have included device id permission in A and the whole code in B which gets deviceId. How can I grant permission for B from A using pending intent. IS there any possibility to do so??

Comment: i just mentioned a permission read_phone_state in app A and i wrote a code which gives me deviceId but didn't mentioned the permission. I just want to pass permission from app A to appB is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible permission are application specific it **cannot be transferred from one app to another**, you can **transfer the information or data between application**.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pass data from one activity to other thorough intent.

In Activity A:-

```
Intent intent=new Intent(A.this,B.class);
intent.putExtra(""DEVICEID",device_id);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity B:-

```
String device_id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DEVICEID");
```

Comment: i just mentioned a permission read_phone_state in app A and i wrote a code which gives me deviceId but didn't mentioned the permission. I just want to pass permission from app A to appB is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. The user approves granting the permission to a specific app. That app cannot then (in secret without the user's knowledge or approval) grant this permission to other apps. That would be a huge security hole and would undermine the entire permissions concept.

Comment: Then instead of making use of pending intent we can use normal intent to transfer data. Were Actually I can use pending intent @david Wasser